# WPF Datagrid example of row details with checkbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I would like to find an example of a WPF Datagrid that has row details with checkboxes in the details. I need to list some data and then present boolean (checkbox) details for each row in that data. I can find examples of how to make the rowdetails appear and what-not but virtually every example uses a text block or something like that - I cant find any with a checkbox that I can also bind to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand what the problem is supposed to be, the following should bind to the  `SomeBoolProperty` of the item.

```
<DataGrid ...>
   <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding SomeBoolProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">Some Bool Property</CheckBox>
        </DataTemplate>
   </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>   
</DataGrid>
```